# How to create a Java matrix that consists of numbers that are the product of 2?

Tags: java, matrix, product

I'm trying to create a 2D int array of numbers that are the product of 2 via user input defining the length of the rows and columns, as the one below:

1  2  4  8

2  4  8 16

4  8 16 32

8 16 32 64

I've only got up to here, and cannot figure out how to make the matrix to start from 1 and to look like the one above. I'd appreciate your help on this one!

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

    int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];

    matrix[0][0] = 1;
    int temp = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = temp * 2;
            temp *= 2;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
```

Comment: Why are you multiplying temp by 2 two times in each iteration? And think about what should happen when the inner loop is done and you're back in the outer loop.

Comment: print your output with temp value each time in inner loop, you will get what's wrong here.

Comment: You don't need a temp variable. The value at position `[i,j]` is `2^(i + j)`, e.g.  `[3,3] = 64`, `[4,4] = 256`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that each element of the matrix would be:

```
matrix[i][j] = (int) Math.pow(2, i+j) ;
```

So, your loop would look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = (int) Math.pow(2, i+j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

int[][] matrix = new int[n][n];

matrix[0][0] = 1;
int temp = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    temp = (int)Math.pow(2, i);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = temp;
        temp *= 2;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```